# Is it "lock a deal" or "lock up a deal" or "lock in a deal"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

> Let's **lock (up/in)** that deal.

I can't find any lexical support for any of these usages. I especially looked at the Free Dictionary's phrases, but nothing under lock up or lock in is relevant.

There's a website called "Lock The Deal", but I wonder if "Let's lock the deal soon" would be something commonly said.

I also came across this:
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/lock-up-deals.1319685/

This is a sentence from Time magazine:

> These governments are desperate to get capital into agriculture," says von Braun, who believes the drive by giant companies to **lock up land deals** could benefit poor African countries whose governments negotiate wisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's **lock in** the terms of our contract.

*lock in* refers to fixing the terms and conditions.

> These giant companies will **lock up** land deals.

*lock up* refers to finalizing the deal.

There is also *lock out* (same meaning as if you were locked out of your house or car):

> After the land deal is completed, other parties will be **locked out**.

meaning other parties (companies) won't be able to purchase/obtain said land.

Comment: There is also *lock down* - which can mean doing something to prevent X from getting away or disappearing.